# How to read the attributes set in model in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to read a attribute from the model using spring boot thymeleaf.

```
@GetMapping("/summary")
public String getSummaryScreen(Model model) {       
    Application application= getApplicationData();
    ClientValidationModel clientValidationModelView = getclientModel();
    model.addAttribute("clientValidationModelView",clientValidationModelView);
    model.addAttribute("application",application);
    return "summary";
}
class application{
   private int applicationNumber;
   private string name;

   ... getter & setter
}
```

In Thymeleaf I am trying to read the application values

```
<div th:text ="${application.applicationNumber}"></div>
```

After removing the space from below comment this is what i see on the browser
org.thymeleaf.context.WebEngineContext$ServletContextAttributesMap@7e8999c3. I expect then application number to be displayed

**Updated**

I noticed that the thymeleaf is not resolving the java object. Even if I try

```
@GetMapping("/summary")
public String getSummaryScreen(Model model) {       
   Application application= getApplicationData();
   ClientValidationModel clientValidationModelView = getclientModel();       
    model.addAttribute("clientValidationModelView",clientValidationModelView);
   model.addAttribute("application","This my application");
   return "summary";
}
```

On the HTML is get only 
"org.thymeleaf.context.WebEngineContext$ServletContextAttributesMap@1f6b5bcf"

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable expression properly, could you only make sure that there is no space in between:

```
<div th:text="${application}"></div>
```

You are trying to read the `application` attribute in summary.html, correct?

Also, can you please try the following for testing purposes:

```
model.addAttribute("application", "test to see if the variable expression works");
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes I am using the right html file and there is no space. I build the project through maven,it worked (I thought spring boot restart should work.) But now I have another issue, where I cannot access the class variable. Edited the questions

Comment: What you write is also correct in my opinion. Please make sure there is no spacing in between: th:text="${application.applicationNumber}">
If it doesn`t work, export the variable applicationNumber to its own model attribute to test:
model.addAttribute("applicationNumber",application.getApplicationNumber());

Comment: Please try my other suggestion then. Also, your getter should be named like this: getApplicationNumber(), for Thymeleaf to recognize it through the variable name.

Comment: I tired model.addAttribute("applicationNumber",application.getApplicationNumber()); But on the html <div th:text="${applicationNumber}"></div> shows up as 
org.thymeleaf.context.WebEngineContext$ServletContextAttributesMap@7e8999c3

Comment: Actually My application class is really Huge one, having lots of nested class, is the issue is due to any memory overflow kind of stuff

Comment: What text do you expect to see with these objects? You have to reach a String or another primitive variable, or override toString() method for the given object, otherwise it will show its address in memory (I think the above is the case) - you can also call the toString() method explicitly like this: th:text="${application.toString()}"

Comment: In my case the applicationNumber is a primitive variable. I thought I would get the value of the application number

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think you have written it correctly, but I unfortunately I cannot help you further, because I do not know what the above message means. Hope somebody else will join it and help.

Comment: Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

After some thoughts, I found the solution that the issue is with the variable name 'applicaiton' I am using to set the model attribute. I am able to solve this by setting the attribute name as "newapplication"